Running VS Code via WSL2 no longer auto-focuses the Terminal tab in panel
I don't know what changed, but after running code . to start a Remote Development session from WSL2 Ubuntu (normally having already entered my virtualenv shell via pipenv) the Panel UI with multiple tabs (Output, Ports, Terminal, etc.) is not longer auto-focused to the Terminal "tab" and instead usually drops me into the Problems or lang. server tab. Sometimes the Panel doesn't come up at all and I have to select Terminal from the top options menu.
I did make some changes to theme and token/syntax customization in settings.json, but is there a way to force my Remote WSL2 session to automatically open the terminal using my default bash profile and have that tab remain open in my UI? I don't need the cursor focus to open there necessarily, but it's one of those minor annoyances that I'd like to fix.
I've tried this forum, Google, the official VS Code docs, and several passes through the settings options. I even asked Codeium inside VS Code about VS Code settings and probably ripped a hole in space/time.
EDIT:
Forgot to post the import specs, like version. This behavior is new to my current version (1.90, May 2024) although of course every time I launch Code for Remote Development from a new python virtualenv in bash, it downloads an update to VS Code Server, which look like incremental commit hashes from the git repo, but I do not know for certain if they are just hash checks for security or actual code commit updates or something else. This behavior did not occur in 1.89 that I can remember and certainly not before that (March 2024).
Version: 1.90.1 (system setup)
Commit: 611f9bfce64f25108829dd295f54a6894e87339d
Date: 2024-06-11T21:01:24.262Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9593362
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


I'm either a big dumb idiot or someone is hacking my gibson, but for whatever reason my window.restoreWindows set to all was not being synced between all profiles. It was set, just not in my Remote Development WSL2 profile until just now, when I went ahead and toggled the simple thing I should have checked first. Cool, cool...
For good measure I also enabled Terminal as workbench.startupEditor in the event nothing was active when I last closed Code.

"window.restoreWindows" is one of the settings that can't exist in a profile-scoped settings.json - it can only go in the global one.

That must be where I went wrong. What's weird is I think it was modified and then continued to be broke or be modified by an extension. I had one using a false bool as a setting variable that in reality only took yes no never. Might have been the other way around, but it would give me syntax errors every time I opened settings.json and had to either grep it out or change it to the right argument. And it came back every Code restart, until I figured it out and yoinked the extension.
